# Use same model table class in universal app for SQLITE

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to use same class for both windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1 project for SQLite database. My model class is this

```
public class person 
    { 

        [MaxLength(5), PrimaryKey] 

        public String name { get; set; } 
        [MaxLength(255)] 
        public String address { get; set; } 
        [MaxLength(11)] 
        public Double phone { get; set; } 
    }
```

I have installed visual studion 2013 extension i.e

- Sqlite for windows runtime
- Sqlite for windows phone 8.1

I have put sqlite-net classess in shared project but I stuck where to put the model person table class so that both project can reuse it . I dont want both project have their own classes.Since both project use same namespace

```
using Sqlite;
```

How to resolve this Need help.

Comment: You can put them in the shared project. The classes added in shared project can be reused in both Windows Phone and Windows project.

Comment: Which namespace will be used?

Comment: The phone project and the Windows RT, and the shared project will all use the same namespace.

Comment: @user3814490 Stuart Smith is right. They will use the same name space.

Comment: If want to have the same files in both with the same namespace and everything you can add the files as linked.